# How do I ensure that the Mac OS X Terminal asks me for my private-key’s password every time I SSH?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal.app

The only time the Mac OS X Terminal seems to ask for my identity file’s password, is when I restart. I’m fairly paranoid, and this seems insecure; how can I ensure it asks for the password *every time* I attempt to use the key?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X do you have ?

Comment: Snow Leopard, 10.6.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ssh-agent stores these for the lifetime of a session (see the ssh-agent options via 'man ssh-agent').  You can shorten the lifetime of a key added to the agent with 'ssh-agent -t 1' but the ss-agent is started by launchd at system startup.  Here is a thread which describes how to deal with the problem:  [apple-discussion](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2135145&tstart=45) .

Comment: Cairo, good tip actually didn't know about the timeout. 
Thanks man.

Comment: That helped, as a matter of fact. I had to dig through that and the associated Reddit thread, but I eventually gave up on completely disabling the `ssh-agent` integration, and instead modified the `org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist` to give me a one-minute timeout. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer, it worked for me. But I think it would be better if you posted the solution here, linking the thread to give credit for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would add the following configuration option to `.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

to disable the use of ssh-agent.

Comment: I can’t vote it up, apparently, because I don’t have enough reputation on SuperUser (I always thought you could vote-up responses to your *own questions*, but… whatever.) Accepted, though! That’s exactly the solution I originally wanted; much better than simply *reducing* the period to a minute or something.

Comment: In retrospect, I’ve changed my accepted answer to the other one; while this apparently achieves the goal, it doesn’t help the deeper problem: that ssh-agent is storing my key at all. With this solution, anybody could walk up, `rm ~/.ssh/config`, and SSH into my machines. (Well, theoretically …)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default (login) keychain to lock on sleep or after a timeout, which also seems to flush the SSH agent.

Open Keychain Access and right-click the login keychain to change settings (I guess you'll want a shorter timeout than me):
[image: Keychain Security Settings]

Or if you prefer a commandline:

```
security set-keychain-settings -lu -t 1   # for a 1 second timeout
```

I was using the org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist change you've mentioned in the comments, but on El Cap you need to disable System Integrity Protection to do that, which I wasn't crazy about. My solution requires an extra prompt to unlock, but it's the cleanest option I've found so far.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only asking you when you log in, then it's being stored in one of two places : in the ssh-agent via ssh-add or via the OSx keychain.

Personally, I'd check the Keychain first as I've a fealing it's probably a safer bet on a GUI centric machine.

Comment: I checked the Keychain, no such luck. It must be `ssh-agent`. How can I fix it to *not* do that? (I’d mark this answer as accepted, except it doesn’t really solve my problem… not without more information…)

Comment: Sorry for the brevity, I wasn't in front of a Mac so I figured I'd give you enough information to be able to find the answer with.

Assuming you didn't find it :
1. Clear ssh-agent : ssh-agent -D
2. The linux geek in me says, just add "unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK" to your ~/.bashrc file. ( You may want to execute it manually as well for it to take effect automatically ). This way, SSH won't know where to find the agent.
3. Disable agent altogether : 
a) launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist
b) i believe a restart would be in order afterwards.